# How to let js make a request from python and preserve the loaded site in place when answered by python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html

Opening a site economizing the data load I seem to run into a need to add more data from Python occasionally.  I use Python with CherryPy and Mako for loading a site.

So, how can I make a JavaScript request from Python to pass me some more data, once the site was loaded already.  I want to do that without moving away from the site.  I know that JavaScript can do all sorts of things, but Python can be a real muscle for me with better debugging features.

Now, I'm not keen on Ajax.  I know nothing about it and I have that fear factor that it would be quite complex.

TIA

Dennis

Comment: [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) makes ajax pretty simple (although the documentation might not look it).

Comment: Can you show me some elementary example of that?  I like jQuery...

Comment: Dont worry jquery really simple thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can make with jQuery like this,
in controller you return rendered template:

```
def some_html():
    return render('my_template.tpl')
```

and in the client side you can use jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
('#result_from_server').load('/some_html');
</script>
```

,where result_from_server its can be id of wrapper div like

```
<div id="result_from_server"></div>
```

and /some_html, url for call your some_html() function.

Very good resurce for quick start with jQuery [jqapi.com](http://jqapi.com)

Comment: Can you help me with this, @Denis.  I just don't know the mechanics involved here.

Comment: Ok, can put your views and templates here and describe what you want to do?

Comment: The data I want to download is arrays, dictionaries, strings etc...  not HTML code.  I do not understand this portion of your code: ".load('/some_html');"  If I terminate the python code with your suggestion "return render('my_template.tpl')", I will move away from the site I called from and I'm in another session.  Right?

Comment: No, you don't understand basics things about "web framework" and "MVC design pattern". You python arrays, strings and etc. Or you want to show it to your end users? I think you need show it in good document representation. If thats true, you must return to client's web browser html code, where you can present desired information.